# Slackware and libvirt with qemu, why vm run as root?

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I configure libvirt to use "users" group to run vm's

```
 grep -w users /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
# unix socket. This prevents unprivileged access from users on the
# unix socket. This prevents unprivileged access from users on the
group = "users"
# deployments. It is strongly recommended that users update their
```

I can launch vm's from user without problem,they run..
But ps said..running as root and not as my unprivileged user,why?

```
ps -ef|grep qemu
root     15248     1 33 14:53 ?        00:01:05 /usr/bin/qemu-kvm -name guest=
```

Is possible to run the vm as unprivileged user?
Distro is slackware 14.2, and of course i'm on users group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

First on libvirt SlackBuild, add or modify those lines

```
VIRTGROUP=${VIRTGROUP:-kvm}

./configure \
  --prefix=/usr \
  --libdir=/usr/lib${LIBDIRSUFFIX} \
  --bindir=/usr/sbin \
  --sbindir=/usr/sbin \
  --disable-static \
  --sysconfdir=/etc \
  --localstatedir=/var \
  --mandir=/usr/man \
  --docdir=/usr/doc/$PRGNAM-$VERSION \
  --enable-static=no \
  --enable-shared=yes \
  --with-qemu-group=$VIRTGROUP \
  --with-qemu-user=nobody \
  --without-hal \
  --with-interface \
  --with-lxc \
  --with-udev \
  --with-storage-disk \
  --with-storage-gluster \
  --with-storage-lvm \
  --with-init-script=none

# udev rules
mkdir -p $PKG/etc/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules
install -D -m 0644 $CWD/65-kvm.rules $PKG/etc/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules
```

udev rules must be like this

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules 
KERNEL=="kvm", NAME="%k", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"
```

Don't forget the polkit part otherwise libvirt run only as root

```
 cat /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/50-libvirt.rules 
// Allow any user in the 'libvirt' group to connect to system libvirtd
// without entering a password.

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.libvirt.unix.manage" &&
        subject.isInGroup("libvirt")) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

After restart libivirt ps return nobody for qemu user

```
ps  -o user,group,cmd -p 14123
USER     GROUP    CMD
nobody   kvm      /usr/bin/qemu-kvm -name guest=..
```